# No such app found after I change my heroku app name

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

When I create a new Heroku app it gives me

**https://obscure-plains-01212.herokuapp.com/**

but this URL is not conventional to my app so I change the app name in the Heroku site **buzzing-api** and then Heroku gives me a new repository
https://git.heroku.com/buzzing-api.git

in stack its shows

Stack  heroku-22 will replace Heroku-20 on the next deploy

So I try to re-deploy in my terminal but says

> remote: !       No such app as obscure-plains-01212.

how can I add a new repository in the previous Heroku repository to avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

You renamed the heroku app so your heroku repository url is also changed. But most probably you didn't change your heroku remote git url in your local project. Running these 2 commands should do the job:

```bash
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/buzzing-api.git
```